# How to read input until the user enters ^X

Tags: c++, string, input, newline

I am creating an interpreter for my esolang, and I need the user to enter some text which then will be interpreted as an INTERCAL program. I want the user to enter text, which may contain any character including newlines, until the user presses ^X (Ctrl-X), like this:

```
Enter your code followed by ^X:
Bla
Blablabla
Bla^X
Thank you for entering your code
```

(line 2, 3 and 4 were entered by the user)

can anyone explain me how I can read input including newlines till the user enters ^X? Thanks

Comment: ^X will have a character value of 24 if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^X has ASCII code 24, try checking for that.

http://www.unix-manuals.com/refs/misc/ascii-table.html

Comment: So should I do something like a do-while loop which readS input character by character and checks if ^X is not entered?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to ask the user to use ^D.
On most systems this produces the EOF character and causes the stream to close.

Thus you do not need to do anything special.
You just read until the end of the input stream. Thus your code can be exactly the same for reading standard input and for reading from a file.

Comment: ^D is not my question. Also, ^D is not in any way involved in HQ9+-ABC